# How to make content appear on separation portions of the page horizontally?

Tags: html, css, horizontal-scrolling

I'm trying to build a horizontal parallax scroll for my page. However, I can't seem to get the  content to appear on different portions of the page, they just all appear on the same portion except vertically apart. Any ideas?

HTML:

```
<div id="transition-slide-container">   
       <div id="transition-slide">
            <div class="slide" id="home">
                <h1>home</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="slide" id="portfolio">
                <h1>portfolio</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="slide" id="about">
                <p>about</p>
            </div>                  
            <div class="slide" id="contact">
                <p>contact<p>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div#transition-slide-container {    
    background: #bee1ff;
    height: 100%;
    padding-top: 128px;
    padding-bottom: 200px;
    width: 400%;
    min-height: 600px;
    z-index: -1;
    overflow: auto;
} 
.slide {
    min-width: 100%;
} 
div#home {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 600px;
} 
div#portfolio{
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 700px;
}
div#about{
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 600px;
}
div#contact {   
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 600px;
 }
```

Website: http://andrewgu12.kodingen.com/
Edit: I realized I wasn't that specific with how I worded my question, what I forgot to add in was i wanted all these to be sectioned off horizontally, like what's seen here: http://markdalgleish.com/projects/stellar.js/

Answer (score 0):

```
div.dx
 {
 width:1012px;
 padding:5px;
 border:1px solid gray;
 margin-left:273px;
 margin-top:15px;
 }
div.ex
 {
 width:1000px;
 padding:5px;
 border:1px solid gray;
 margin-left:273px;
 margin-top:5px;
 }
```

How CSS formatting works is, if you have specified leftfor a block, then for placing the next block, you shall specify margin greater than 0. As for auto, it'll start marginalizing from absolute position. So all of the content may appear in one block and will be jumbled.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stack these slides into the content area, you'll want to add the following:

```
div#transition-slide-container {
    position: relative;
}
```

and

```
div#transition-slide-container .slide {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

This will position the slides absolutely relative to their container, one on top of the other.

Since the slide divs are all meant to have the same dimensions, there is no need to declare them individually. The `div#home` , `div#portfolio` etc can be removed

now you add your content to your slides and position / animate / show / hide it on a per-slide basis,